# Regresar boton al color Original C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo el codigo para que al seleccionar el boton se pinte de otro color, pero ahora quiero que al volverlo a presionar se regrese al boton al color de origen, este es mi codigo.

```
  private void roundedButtonGray1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.roundedButtonGray1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
```

Intente poniendo una condicional tipo

```
private void roundedButtonGray1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
if(roundedButtonGray1.Click == true){
            this.roundedButtonGray1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
}
```

Pero no me deja utilizar el evento click, no se cual debo usar, alguna orientación la agradeceria.
Estoy usando WINFORM

Comment: estas usando windows form o wpf?

Comment: Windows form disculpa, ya edite

Comment: agrega tambien la etiqueta de windows form por favor

Comment: En el evento click del boton preguntas lo siguiente: si el color del boton es igual a verde, entonces al boton se le asgina el color original. De lo contrario se le asgina el color verde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podria ser algo como esto

```
private void roundedButtonGray1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(roundedButtonGray1.BackColor == Color.Green){
        this.roundedButtonGray1.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
    } else {
        roundedButtonGray1.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

validas si es de color verde y lo pones en el gris original, pero sino esta en verde lo pones en ese color

Nota: valida cual es el color original del boton en las propiedades, pero recuerdo que estaba dentro de `SystemColors`

Comment: Funciona Perfecto, gracias

Answer (score 0):

En el error es por que [Click](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click?view=netframework-4.7.2) no es una propiedad, es un evento.

> Se produce cuando se hace clic en el control.

Puedes crear una bandera que cambie al momento de dar click en el boton;

```
bool buttonGrayClicked = false;
private void roundedButtonGray1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.roundedButtonGray1.BackColor = buttonGrayClicked ? <color default> : Color.Green;

    buttonGrayClicked = !buttonGrayClicked;
}
```